# python3.5 multiprocessing pool hangs repeatedly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing.Pool to create a pool of workers to load files into Pandas.  It hangs *all* the time, probably about 75% of the time.

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp

def load(filename):
    thing = pd.read_table(filename)
    return thing

files = ['a','b','c'] # A list of a bunch of files
with mp.Pool(5) as pool:
    result = pool.map(load, files)
```

By "hangs" I mean never finishes.  I've straced the procs and they are waiting on futuexes, so I have no idea what that means.  Am I invoking the pool correctly?

Again, it works *perfectly* 25% of the time, so I must be doing something right... thx!

Ubuntu Xenial Python3.5.2

Comment: This seems like an inefficient way to read to read a table - it needs to be reserialized to get back to the parent process. Are these files large enough to eat through available memory? You may end up with with multiple times the size of all of these files in memory commitments.

Comment: I tried it with threads instead, that was a disaster because of something that you don't see above (there are some pure Python functions that get called inside of load()).  Yeah, the pickling across processes seems inefficient but it's actually not a bottleneck at all.